# STM32 can use variable 64bit?

Tags: arm, stm32

I use IAR, how to use 64bit variable for 64 bit integer Arithmetic?

Comment: I wouldnt call it off topic, it is lacking in research heavily, which is the downvote button, but it seems like a reasonable question to field here.

Comment: I agree, downvoting but not voting to close.

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming that you want C?

```
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{
    // uint64_t = unsigned
    // int64_t = signed
    uint64_t x = 0xFFFFFFFFFFF;
    uint64_t y = 0x1111122222333;
    uint64_t z = x + y;
}
```

The 64-bit types can also be specified more explicitly:

`unsigned long long a;` (unsigned)

`long long b;` (signed)